# Node - Can't Get moment.js to compile in VSCode (module and require problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

I have been using an online ide to put together my node app, but now I am trying to get it to run on my local computer.  At this time, I am now running into an issue with starting it up: when I use the terminal to run "node app.js" I get the following error message:

```
\node_modules\moment\moment.js:7
import { hooks as moment, setHookCallback } from './lib/utils/hooks';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have found that the answer to fixing this issue is to add "type": "module" to the package.json file in the directory.  However, when I add that to it and I try to run the application again, I get this error message:

```
app.js:2
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
                   ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Here are my imports:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
methodOverride   = require("method-override"),
mongoose         = require("mongoose"),
express          = require("express"),
moment           = require("moment"),
app              = express();
```

So I am unsure why I cannot get both to work so my app can run; I am sure this is something simple but I am at a loss.  Thank you.

Comment: what version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: I have Node.js v12.18.0

Comment: What exactly causes the call of `\node_modules\moment\moment.js`? It's a client side script. Please add more of the app.js code. `require("moment")` alone doesn't trigger this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add type = module you tell the compiler that you are using ES6 modules type in the application. So, now you can't use require anymore.
Better way to fix the initial problem is to uninstall moment.js and try reinstalling some compatible version. As per my observation, error raised in the installed moment.js.

Comment: This was the exact problem; I reinstalled the dependency and now it works perfectly.  I knew the answer was probably so simple as this, but couldn't think of it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use `require` in NodeJS.

The moment.js script is not meant to be used in server-side JavaScript that way. Use `require('moment')` instead:

```
const moment = require('moment');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

Comment: Oh, I should have included that part in my question above.  I do have const moment = require('moment') at the top of my app.js file already, and am still receiving that error.

Comment: That error should be impossible. See on [RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/moment). Can you add more of the app.js script? Can you add the stack trace of the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error

Comment: So, it seems that I had the incorrect version of Moment.js installed in the first place, which is why it was throwing this error even though it should have been impossible.  Reinstalling it seems to have fixed the issue.  Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: As I said below, it seems the simple answer was that the incorrect version of moment was installed, as simply reinstalling it fixed my issue.  I had assumed it was the correct version since it worked fine in my online ide, but I see that somehow it was not installed correctly int he first place.  Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

in place of - app.js:2
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

can you try with -
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'